# Prolog create list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm having some (or a lot of) trouble with lists of lists in prolog.

So I have a list of numbers, say [5,6,1,3] as input.
The output should be [[5,25],[6,36],[1,1],[3,9]].

I already have a predicate that 'return's the 2 item lists (keep in mind that I'll have to change the get_squared_pair function to get some other relevant value):

```
get_squared_pair(Number, Result) :-
get_squared_value(Number, SquareValue),
Result = [Number, SquareValue].

get_squared_value(Number, Result) :-
Result is Number * Number.
```

Until here it's pretty logical. Now I need a predicate that recursively iterates though a list, adds the squared pair to a new list, and then returns this lists of lists. What I have right now is:

```
return_list([], 0).
return_list([Head | Tail], Result) :-
get_squared_pair(Head, Add),
append(Add,Result),
return_list(Tail, Result).
```

This doesn't work for a number of reasons, and it's mostly because I can't seem to figure out how the recursion actually works with lists, much less lists of lists. Also it's currently running in the wrong order which doesn't help.

I understand this might be a bit vague but I've tried googling my way out of this one but can't seem to translate what I find into my own problem very well.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Prolog does not have *functions* that define operations. It has *predicates* that define relations. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Excellent point, and I'm still very new to prolog so forgive my ignorance. I did put a predicate tag on this post from the start, but I forgot to also reflect this in the actual text... too caught up in old habits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your `get_squared_pair/2` first. Although it's working, it can be tidied up a bit which will also help understand how Prolog works. The primary mechanism of Prolog is *unification*, which is not the same as *assignment* which occurs in other languages. In *unification*, Prolog examines two terms and attempts to *unify* them by instantiating variables in one or both of the terms to make them match. There are some predicates in Prolog, like `is/2` which are used to evaluate expressions in one argument, and then unify the first argument with that result.

Your first predicate, then, which you have written as:

```
get_squared_pair(Number, Result) :-
    get_squared_value(Number, SquareValue),
    Result = [Number, SquareValue].

get_squared_value(Number, Result) :-
    Result is Number * Number.
```

Can be simplified in two ways. First, you can consolidate the `get_squared_value/2` since it's just one line and doesn't really need its own predicate. And we'll rename the predicate so it's not imperative.

```
square_pair(Number, Square) :-
    S is Number * Number,     % Square the number
    Square = [Number, S].     % Unify Square with the pair
```

Prolog can unify terms in the *head* of the clause, so you can avoid the redundant unification. So this is all you need:

```
square_pair(Number, [Number, Square]) :-
    Square is Number * Number.
```

On to the main predicate, `return_list/2`. First, we'll rename this predicate to `square_pairs`. When doing recursion with lists, the most common pattern is to continue reducing a list until it is empty, and then a base case handles the empty list. Your implementation does this, but the base case is a little confused since the 2nd argument is an integer rather than a list:

```
square_pairs([], 0).
```

This really should be:

```
square_pairs([], []).
```

Your main predicate clause isn't making correct use of `append/2`. There are two forms of `append` in SWI Prolog: `append/2` and `append/3`. You can look up what these do in the SWI Prolog online documentation. I can tell you that, in Prolog, *you cannot change the value of a variable within a predicate clause once it's been instantiated except through backtracking*. For example, look at the following sequence that might be in a predicate clause:

```
X = a,    % Unify X with the atom 'a'
X = b,    % Unify X with the atom 'b'
```

In this case, the second expression will *always* fail because `X` is already unified and cannot be unified again. However, if I have this:

```
foo(X),    % Call foo, which unifies X with a value that makes 'foo' succeed
bar(X, Y), % Call bar, which might fail based upon the value of 'X'
```

In the above case, if `bar(X, Y)` fails, then Prolog will *backtrack* to the `foo(X)` call and seek another value of `X` which makes `foo(X)` succeed. If it finds one, then it will call `bar(X, Y)` again with the new value of `X`, and so on.

So `append(Add, Result)` does not append `Add` to `Result` yielding a new value for `Result`. In fact, `append` with two arguments says that the second list argument is the concatenation of all the elements of the first list, assuming the first argument is a list of lists, so the definition of `append/2` doesn't match anyway.

When thinking about your recursion, realize that the argument lists are in one-to-one correspondence with each other. The head of the result list is the "square pair" for the head of the list in the first argument. Then, recursively, the tail of the 2nd argument is a list of the square pairs for the tail of the first argument. You just need to express that in Prolog.  We can also use the technique I described above for unification within the *head* of the clause.

```
square_pairs([Head | Tail], [SqPair | SqTail]) :-
    square_pair(Head, SqPair),
    square_pairs(Tail, SqTail).
square_pairs([], []).
```

Now there's another simplification we can do, which is eliminate the `square_pair/2` auxiliary predicate completely:

```
square_pairs([Head | Tail], [[Head, SqHead] | SqTail]) :-
    SqHead is Head * Head,
    square_pairs(Tail, SqTail).
square_pairs([], []).
```

There's a handy predicate in Prolog called `maplist` which can be used for defining a relationship which runs parallel between two lists, which is the scenario we have here. We can bring back the `square_pair/2` predicate and use `maplist`:

```
square_pairs(Numbers, SquarePairs) :-
    maplist(square_pair, Numbers, SquarePairs).
```

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborate and descriptive answer! Learned a lot from this. Definitely crystallised some of the prolog concepts in my mind. I'll have to read it a few more times to fully understand it though ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

So you want to turn your list into another, such that each element (a number) is turned into a two-element list, the number and its square.

All you need to do is to tell that to Prolog. First, the second one:

```
turn_into_two(Num, [A,B]):-
```

what is `A`?

```
    A is Num,
```

what is `B`? We just tell it to Prolog, too:

```
                B is ... * ... .
```

Now, on to our list. A list `[A|B]` in Prolog consists of its head element `A`, and its tail `B` - unless it's an empty list `[]` of course. It doesn't matter *what* the list's elements are; a list is a list.

We need to account for all cases, or else we're not talking about lists but something else:

```
turn_list([], Res):-
```

so what is our result in case the list was empty? It should be empty as well, right?

```
    Res = ... .
```

in the other case,

```
turn_list([A|B], Res):-
```

our result won't be empty, so it'll have *its* head and tail, correct?

```
    Res = [C|D],
```

next we say what we know about the heads: the input list's head turns into that two elements list we've described above, right?

```
    turn_into_two(A,C),
```

and then we say our piece about the tails. But what do we know about the tails? We know that one is the result of the conversion of the other, just as the whole list is:

```
    turn_list( ... , ...) .
```

And that's it. Incidentally, what we've described, follows the paradigm of *mapping*. We could have used any other predicate in place of `turn_into_two/2`, and *it* would get called for each of the elements of the input list together with the corresponding element from the resulting list.